# How to SELECT rows with MAX based on three columns

Tags: mysql, sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

My tables are defined as follows

#### software

```
software_uid  name 
-------------|----------
1            | word 
2            | excel
```

#### platform

```
platform_uid  name 
-------------|----------
1            | windows 
2            | osx
```

#### downloads

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `downloads` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`software_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`platform_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`version` decimal(2,1) NOT NULL,
`build` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`path` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And here is some data from downloads table:

```
INSERT INTO `downloads` (`id`, `software_uid`, `platform_uid`, `version`, `build`, `path`, `date_added`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, '0.4', 'Alpha 1', 'downloads/word0.4a1win.zip', '2015-02-06 08:15:09'),
(2, 1, 2, '0.4', 'Alpha 1', 'downloads/word0.4a1osx.zip', '2015-02-06 08:29:47'),
(4, 1, 1, '0.5', 'Beta', 'downloads/word0.5bwin.zip', '2015-02-06 08:29:52'),
(5, 2, 1, '0.1', 'PreAlpha', 'downloads/excel0.1pawin.zip', '2015-02-06 09:14:32');
```

I wanted to pull two types of data based from tables (which are basically two queries):

1. One which will show latest build of all software for all platforms
2. One for other downloads which excludes 1st one

and on the end append names from software and platform table.

I have started building several levels of sub queries and got into one really nasty query:

```
SELECT `name`,`path`,`os`,`version`,`build` 
FROM `platform` AS s4 
JOIN 
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM `software` AS `s2` 
    JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT 
           `software_uid` AS `guid`, `platform_uid`, MAX(`version`) AS `version`, 
           `path`, `build` 
        FROM `downloads` 
        GROUP BY `platform_uid`, `software_uid` 
    ) AS `s1` ON `s1`.`guid`=`s2`.`software_uid`
) 
AS s3 ON s3.`platform_uid` = s4.`platform_uid`;
```

which gave **some** of the fields correctly. `GROUP BY` clause was the source of the problems, or to be precise the first sub-query executed didn't fetched results as intended because it was not defined correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `group by`, you should not have any fields that are neither in the `group by` nor in aggregation functions.  So, `path` and `build` are inappropriate in the subquery.  Instead, you have to bring them in with another `join`.  Just because you do `max()` doesn't mean the other fields come from the same row.

```
SELECT `name`,`path`,`os`, d.`version`, d.`build` 
FROM platform p  JOIN 
     software s
     on s.`platform_uid` = p.`platform_uid` JOIN
     (SELECT `software_uid` AS `guid`, `platform_uid`,
             MAX(`version`) AS `version`
      FROM `downloads` 
      GROUP BY `software_uid`, `platform_uid`
     ) dd
     ON s.`guid`= dd.`software_uid` join
     downloads d
     on d.software_uid = dd.guid and d.platform_uid = dd.platfrom_uid and
        d.version = dd.version;
```

In addition, you have a problem with naming conflicts -- `name` is in more than one table.  You should always use table aliases to qualify column names.  I replaced your aliases with abbreviations for the table names; this makes it easier to follow the query logic.